# How to make a div align to the right side of the parent while maintaining its vertical position?

Tags: css, positioning, vertical-alignment

Please refer to this handy diagram I drew:

[image]

`div1`'s height is unknown. `div3`'s width is fluid; it should never overlap `div2`. Both `div1` and `div2` have the same width and are horizontally centered via `margin: auto`. How can I position `div3` so that it aligns to the **right side of `body`** (no matter how wide `body` is) while sharing vertical position with `div2`? (Using CSS)

Answer (score 33):

```css
.div1{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    border:5px solid #995555;
}
.div2{
    width:100px;
    margin:0 auto;
    border:5px solid #aaaa55;
    height:200px;
}
.div3{
    float:right;
    width:50px;
    height:100px;
    border:5px solid cyan;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">div1</div>
<div class="div3">div3</div>
<div class="div2">div2</div>
```

Demo also at http://jsfiddle.net/XjC9z/1/

Comment: @Arendax pretty sure it works if the parent div has dimensions. Please post an example with the problem.

Comment: It was aligning with the right of the page. It was a problem in my Jquery. It is fixed now.

Comment: *div3 should never overlap div2*

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

HTML:

```
<div id='container'>
    <div id='first'>1</div>
    <div id='second'>2</div>
    <div id='third'>3</div>
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#container{
    width: 100px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

#first{
    border: 1px solid #ff55ff;
}
#second{
    border: 1px solid #55ff77;
}

#third{
    border: 1px solid #448855;
}
#first,
#second{
    width: 50px;
    clear:both;

    float:left;
}

#third{
    clear:none;
    float: left;
}
```

​

See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zaNvR/1/

Comment: I've updated and clarified my question. The 3rd div should align with the `body`'s right side, not the 2nd div's left side.

Answer (score 1):

A simple div grid would do the trick:

http://jsfiddle.net/NUGPv/

```
<div class="con">
    <div class="lft">div 1</div>
    <div class="rgt"></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="lft">div 2</div>
    <div class="rgt">div 3</div>    
</div>​

.con { overflow:hidden; }
.lft { width:100px; height:100px; float:left; }
.rgt { width:100px; height:100px; float:left; }
```

Simply leave the the top right cell empty.

Comment: Doesn't that align `div3` by the right side of `div2`? If `body`'s width is more than `.lft` and `.rgt`'s width combined, `div3` wouldn't be aligned by the `body`'s right side, would it?

Comment: As I play with this fiddle, I see that removing the "con" class from the first outer div causes the second outer div to be displayed on the same line as the first outer div. Can anyone please explain what overflow:hidden is doing to that first div?